# Using multiple check boxes in place of using custom list view to display list

Tags: android, android-listview, android-checkbox

Is it a good idea to use multiple check boxes and form the list myself if I don't want to features of ListView. 
I have to create custom check boxes with box on the left, which is easy while using check box. I know this restricts me from using the functions of the list but it is easier to do this rather create a custom layout every time.(Processing time will be less I suppose.)

If I can have check box on the left without creating custom list, that will be the best solution to this but unfortunately list view doesn't have the feature and you have to create a custom list.

Comment: you want a ListView with list items as checkboxes on the left and text on the right??

Comment: then just use a checkbox in the ListView item layout. By default the checkbox is on the left and Text is on the right

Comment: @Archie.bpgc - Will there be any performance issues if I use checkboxes in place of list. (I have approximately 50 items in my list to display.)

Answer (score 0):

The decision depends on the number of rows (checkboxes in your case) and the origin of them.

If you have to fetch an indetermined number of checkboxes from a server, or it's a list of checkboxes that the user can grow to infinite, you should use a ListView.

On the other hand, if the number of rows sis known beforehand and it's always the same and not very  big, you are not bound to use ListView. You might use ScrollView if it's easier for you, placing inside your custom checkboxes.

Comment: Thx. I have limited input and will make it custom using scroll view. :)